# Epsilon delta of recursively defined function

Tags: limits

I was wondering if the following can be proved with the definition of limits:

$$a_0=1$$
$$a_{n+1}=a_n-\frac{(a_n)^2-5}{2a_n}$$

The thing to prove is $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\sqrt5$$

Comment: It might behoove you to rewrite the recursion term as $$a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+5}{2a_n}.$$

Comment: Do you have to use the raw definition of a limit to prove this? If not, there are better methods to use.

Comment: I disagree with the suggested rewriting. The form you have it in is immediately recognized as the Newton–Raphson method on the equation $x^2 = 5$. Wikipedia has an [analysis of the convergence of this method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Proof_of_quadratic_convergence_for_Newton.27s_iterative_method).

Comment: I know there are better methods, but I wanted to see if anyone could do this with the raw definition. I think that would be an interesting challenge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_{n+1}-\sqrt{5} = \frac{(a_n-\sqrt{5})^2}{2a_n}\tag{1}$$
and we may prove by induction that $3=a_1>a_2>a_3>\ldots\geq \sqrt{5}$. Since $\left|a_2-\sqrt{5}\right|<\frac{1}{10}$,
by $(1)$ we have
$$ \left| a_{n+2}-\sqrt{5} \right| <\frac{1}{10^{2^n}},\tag{2} $$
that implies $\lim_{n\to +\infty} a_n=\sqrt{5}$ as wanted.